# How to save an audio file in internal storage android

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder, internal-storage

I was wondering how can I save an audio file in the Internal storage of my android device. Specifically I would like my app that records sound from the microphone to save this file in the internal storage. I know that for external storage there is something like:

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myrecord.3gpp";
```

Is there anything similar for internal storage also?
Thanks!

Comment: Check My Answer....it is realy helpfull

Comment: http://codetheory.in/android-saving-files-on-internal-and-external-storage/

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
outputFile="/sdcard/myrecord.3gpp";
```

Comment: Didn't he say he wants internal storage? The sdcard is external.