# How to save an audio recorded in internal storage

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-internal-storage

The android application I am working on; it has an option of audio-recording; I want it to save a new audio recorded file in internal storage of a device so that no neither user nor other applications will be able to access to those recorded audio files, unless they open my application.

My main struggle is to be able to save that audio file in internal storage: I took my time to review in my android programming books and read some questions and answers here : [How to save an audio file in internal storage android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661338/how-to-save-an-audio-file-in-internal-storage-android) and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_internal_storage.htm but unfortnately things I am getting from there are not settling my problem at all.

The codes that I am using to record are here below :

```
        private MediaRecorder rec;
        private String file_folder="/scholar/";


          String 
          file_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

            File file= new File(file_path,file_folder);

            Long date=new Date().getTime();
            Date current_time = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));

            rec=new MediaRecorder();

            rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            rec.setAudioChannels(1);
            rec.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
            rec.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
            rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            if (!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            /*the file here this one:File file= new File(file_path,file_folder);
            it means the value of the outputfile is the one which will be provided by 
            rec.setOutputFile() method, so it will be saved as this name: 

            file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"_"+current_time+".amr"

            */
            rec.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"_"+current_time+".amr");

            try {
                rec.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Recording_Service.this,"Sorry! file creation failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            rec.start();

               rec.stop();
               rec.reset();
```

Unfortunately what I am doing there, is saving my file on external storage, it means after recording, the file is visible to everyone in a device file explorer, they can even delete the file.

So! Please, I need your help guys, if any help, I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What issues do you have with getFilesDir()? (the solution in first answer you linked to)

Comment: `+"/"+"_"+current_time+".amr"` Pretty rough code! Please tell to which file name this evaluates. Value please.

Comment: `if (!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
            }`. Check the return value of mkdirs()! Change to `if (!file.exists()) if (!file.mkdirs()){ Toast(...sorry could not create directory ...); return;}
            `

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }` If you catch an exception then display a Toast() to the user saying so. And return; You are now blindly calling .start().

Comment: @Okas Whenever I try to use that getFilesDir(), my app crashes: File file= new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/.scholar");  if (!file.exists()){
                    file.mkdirs();
                }   rec.setOutputFile(new File(file+"/"+"ab"+sdf+"_o.amr"));  Or may be I am not using it rightly.

Comment: @greenapps Actually what I want is to save that recorded file into internal storage

Comment: Please put all your code in your post. Use extra code blocks to do so. We do not like to read code in comments. Do you? Also apply the extra code for mkdirs() which i suggested right away.

Comment: `Actually what I want is to save that recorded file into internal storage` Yes we know. We already long time know. Why do you repeat the obvious? But your formulation is strange. You have no recorded file that you then/afterwards wanna save to internal storage. What you want is let the recording be saved to a file in internal storage.

Comment: @greenapps I updated the code; and that code is running but saving the file in external storage.

Comment: Of course it saves in external storage. You should use getFilesDir() instead. Please adapt your code. And now there are two calls to mkdirs(). Wrong! Remove the first one. Adapt your code please. And you are not returning if mkdir() fails. Read my comment, you should return then. Adapt your code please.

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } If you catch an exception then display a Toast() to the user saying so. And return; You are now blindly calling .start().` !@#$% Why did you not apply that suggestion? Do you want help or not?

Comment: And you have not supplied requested info on `+"/"+"_"+current_time+".amr" Pretty rough code! Please tell to which file name this evaluates. Value please. ` .

Comment: @greenapps Now The codes are updated, if I have got very well what I am being requested to fill. And another issue is that, I couldn't be able to  adapt my code using that getFilesDIr(); so please if an help, I will sincerely appreciate it. thanks again for the precious intervention

Comment: My god.. read what i said about all around mkdirs(). And i still do not see a getFilesDir().

Comment: `Toast.makeText(Recording_Service.this,"Sorry! file creation failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` ? File creation? prepare() failed. And you should also display e.getMessage() as there you will be informed about the cause. I expect you to update all.

Comment: You have the same toast twice. How would the user know which one it is? And the first one is no file creation but directory creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had found the answer of this question, I used `getFilesDir()`;

```
       private MediaRecorder rec;
       String file_path=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();

            File file= new File(file_path);

            Long date=new Date().getTime();
            Date current_time = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));

            rec=new MediaRecorder();

            rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            rec.setAudioChannels(1);
            rec.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
            rec.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
            rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            if (!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            String file_name=file+"/"+current_time+".3gp";
            rec.setOutputFile(file_name);

         try {
                    rec.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(Recording_Service.this,"Sorry! file creation failed!"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                rec.start();

           rec.stop();
           rec.reset();
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me for the answer. Let's continue to enjoy coding to make our world more sweet pleasant and enjoyable.